# Hibernate-Search with Lucene without database?

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I like the way hibernate encapsulates the `lucene` logic with annotation-based configuration.

It is possible to user `hibernate-search` as an adapter for lucene, but without an underlying database (as I only need the lucene index, no db)?

Comment: As I understand, Hibernate-lucene project is an adapter for Lucene to work seamlessly with Hibernate. If you just need Lucene, why not just using Lucene libraries without anything extra? What's in Hibernate-Lucene that you need?

Comment: hibernate-search provides annotation-based configuration for lucene. I like that very much.